# Compare values of two tables and for results export JSON

Tags: php, mysql, compare, json, nested-loops

I have **two different tables**. For those I **select some results**. 
On the first based on a min/max and for the second based on Lat/Lng. That's easy (don't pay much attention on the values) and is created by:

```
$sql1="SELECT * FROM events WHERE value BETWEEN '".$min2d."' AND '".$max2d."'";
$sql2="SELECT * FROM locations WHERE (lng BETWEEN ".$wl." AND ".$el.") AND (lat BETWEEN '".$sl."'AND'".$nl."')";
```

Now that we have downsized the results, we want to **match the `'id'`** row of the first table if **exists** on the second table. On success we create results.

So let's get some numbers first:

```
$result1 = mysql_query($sql1);
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);

$numRows1 = mysql_num_rows($result1);
$numRows2 = mysql_num_rows($result2);

$loopCount1 = 1;
$loopCount2 = 1;
```

For more efficient parsing of the **JSON** (from a user) we want to sort the events by creating them into a JSON array with the location as a 'holder'. So that means, each location might have several events.

**Some locations might not have events**, but also some **events might not correspond to a location**. Our only comparing method is by the same `'id'`.

With my following try, which is of course buggy creates for *all* (that's wrong) locations results even if for those without events. And that's where I need your precious help.

```
$json = '{"markers":[';
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
    $json .= '{"coordinates": { "lat":'. $row2['lat'] .', "lng" : ' . $row2['lng'] .'},'
            .'{"events" : [';
    while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
        if ($row1['id']=$row2['id'])
            $json .= '{ '   
                    .'"title": "'.$row1['title'].'",'
                    .'"info": "'.$row1['info'].'",'
                    .'"}';
        // add comma for Json if not final row
        if ($loopCount1 < $numRows1) {
            $json .= ', ';
            $loopCount1++;}
        }
    $json .= ']}}';
    // add comma for Json if not final row
    if ($loopCount2 < $numRows2) {
            $json .= ', ';
            $loopCount2++;}
    }
$json .= ']}';
```

And finally an echo:

```
echo $json;
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using a JOIN instead of doing your own matching between the two queries? And why are you creating the JSON by hand instead of using `json_encode()`?

Comment: Your inner while-loop will only work on the first iteration of the outer loop, because it fetches all the results of `$sql1`, and there's nothing left to fetch the next time.  You need to do `mysql_data_seek($result1, 0);` before the inner loop to reset it back to the beginning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To compare values of two tables and print results as json please use below code,

```
<?php
      /* connect to the db */
      $link = mysql_connect('localhost','username','password') or die('Cannot connect to the DB');
      mysql_select_db('db_name',$link) or die('Cannot select the DB');

      /* grab the posts from the db */
      $query1 = "SELECT * FROM test1";
      $result1 = mysql_query($query1,$link) or die('Error query:  '.$query1);

      $query2 = "SELECT * FROM test2";
      $result2 = mysql_query($query2,$link) or die('Error query:  '.$query2);

      /* create one master array of the records */
      $posts = array();
      if(mysql_num_rows($result1) && mysql_num_rows($result2)) {
        while($post1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
            $post2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);
            if($post1['name'] == $post2['name'])
              $posts[] = array('test1'=>$post1,'test2'=>$post2);
        }
      }

     header('Content-type: application/json');
     echo json_encode(array('posts'=>$posts));

      /* disconnect from the db */
      @mysql_close($link);
?>
```